# Ubuntu 14.04 I can't get SSH tunneling to work with -g switch?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh-tunneling

I'm running this command on myServer:

```
ssh -g -p 9922 -f myuser@serverOnOpenInternet -L 1212:serverBehindFirewall:80 -N
```

serverOnOpenInternet runs sshd on port 9922. (not my call)

Once I run the command in question on myServer, I can do:

```
wget http://localhost:1212/
```

and successfully reach the index page of serverBehindFirewall.

BUT: if I try from another machine to hit:

```
http://myServer:1212/
```

The connection times out and I can't connect through the tunnel to serverBehindFirewall.

I've tested the -g switch on my mac and verified that it works like I'd expect from there. I know these are different versions/implementations of ssh. But from everything I can glean, ssh on Ubuntu 14.04 should support the -g switch as well. (it's mentioned in the man page)

Please help :)

Comment: Perhaps you have a firewall on `myserver` which prevents access to port 1212?

Comment: @lambert it's a pretty standard ubuntu 14.04 LTS install.. but I will double check ..

Comment: Could you check which interface 1212 is bound on, paste the output of ` netstat -ntl |grep 1212`

Comment: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1212            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
that's my ssh tunnel connection that I've opened.

Comment: And the client is able to resolve `myserver`? I do think so because you will have a message indicating the host couldn't be resolved instead of the timeout message you are receiving but to double check...

Comment: And the 'serverBehindFirewall` has port 80 still opened? Have you tried `tcpdump host serverBehindFirewall and port 80` on `serverOnOpenInternet` to see if you have traffic over your tunneled port?

Comment: @YitzJacob Please add the netstat command and its output to your question.

Comment: Guys, I managed to get one of my servers to work with @jofel's answer .. which has since been deleted. ?  (I was just trying to confirm w/ a second server to see if this really solved the problem)

Comment: Can you post the answer then yourself?

Comment: Try running ssh with -v and possibly without -N and -f and this should spit out some errors in the terminal that will be helpful in debugging where the problem is really occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to specify a bind address on the -L option. Like:

`-L 192.168.1.100:1212:serverBehindFirewall:80`

as requested, paste from below:

Option "GatewayPorts" set to "yes" in /etc/ssh/ssh_config fixed the problem.

This obviously does (almost) the same, as specifying "GatewayPorts yes". It binds to the specified address. The Option "GatewayPorts yes" automatically binds to the wildcard address (0.0.0.0), enabling remote clients to connect. If not specified, and no IP-Address is used to bind to (-L  :  :  :  ) , then only the loopback address 127.0.0.1 is bound, so no remote hosts can connect

Comment: Sorry, and that address should be what? The address of serverBehindFirewall, serverOnOpenInternet or myServer ?

Comment: :) Of course it is the address of the machine providing the tunnel  ...

Comment: This obviously does (almost) the same, as specifying "GatewayPorts yes". It binds to the specified address.
The Option "GatewayPorts yes" _automatically_ binds to the wildcard address (0.0.0.0), enabling remote clients to connect. If not specified, and _no_ IP-Address is used to bind to (-L <IP> : <LOCAL_PORT> : <REMOTE_IP> : <REMOTE_PORT> ) , then only the loopback address 127.0.0.1 is bound, so no remote hosts can connect.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! Ok, Along with your comment for explanation this would be a complete answer :)  so please add this info to your answer including GatewayPorts yes and I can mark yours as the correct answer.